# How do ingesting value from xml/pdf/csv to splunk or solr?

Tags: xml, solr, splunk

I want to get the value from xml or csv or pdf file via using splunk or solr. How i import these format file into splunk and solr?

I have tried import xml file into solr but it doesnt fit solr schema.
Besides, i have no idea to import file into splunk.

Comment: XML and CVS files are plain text and easily ingested by Splunk. PDF files are not text and cannot be ingested by Splunk without some kind of pre-processing.
We'll need to hear more about what you want to to do with these files to offer specific advise. Are these one-time adds or will the files be monitored for changes?  There's an entire course on getting data into Splunk so a forum like will only scratch the surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the CSV or XML files to Splunk, you can use the Settings > Add Data, and then upload the files you are interested in.

You can process XML once its ingested by using the `xmlkv` or `spath` commands. This will extract fields from the data, which makes it easier to work with. You may also be able to set the `kv_mode=xml` in `props.conf`, as outlined in the docs for [props.conf](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Admin/Propsconf).

To read PDF, you'll need some other tool to convert this into a readable format, such as [pdf2text](http://launchpad.net/pdf2text)

Comment: Thanks, where is the props.conf located in splunk file?

Comment: props will be located under etc/system/local/props.conf . I strongly suggest you have a read of https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Admin/Aboutconfigurationfiles